# Where does the phrase "more than a fluke" come from?

Tags: phrases

Can you tell me where "more than a fluke" comes from?

Comment: "more than a fluke" is not a set phrase. See fluke at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluke (**3**)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misconception that the expression is a set-phrase/ idiom. 

Answer (score 2):

A [fluke](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluke) is a chance occurrence:

> fluke 3  
>   n.
>   1. A stroke of good luck.
>   2. A chance occurrence; an accident.
>   3. Games An accidentally good or successful stroke in billiards or pool.

So, *more than a fluke* means that something was more than simple luck. It is not really an idiom as such, more of a natural expression. In the same way as you would say *it is more than his age* or *it is more than a car* or whatever. It is a typical usage of a fairly common word.